# How to get number value from the input field into Bootstrap modal?

Tags: javascript, html

It should be a trivial task but for some reason I cannot pass/get the value from the input field into Boostrap 4 modal. When I use the following code it does show all the information BUT the value of the input `this.qtyAskValue = document.querySelector("#qtyAsk").value.trim()`. Any idea what is wrong with my JS code? I am trying to solve the issue with plain vanilla JS.

**HTML**

```
<input type="number" id="qtyAsk" name="qtyAsk" placeholder="0">
<button type="button" id="buyTicket" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModalCenter">Buy</button>
```

**JavaScript**

```
const buyTicket = document.querySelector("#buyTicket")
buyTicket.addEventListener("click", getModalInfo)

class UI {
  constructor() {
    this.show = document.querySelector("#modalContent")
    this.qtyAskValue = document.querySelector("#qtyAsk").value.trim()
  }
  showData() {
    this.show.innerHTML = `<div class="modal-header">
      <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalCenterTitle">Modal title</h5>
      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
      </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
      <p>You are placing an order for ${this.qtyAskValue} shares</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>`
  }
}
const ui = new UI()

function getModalInfo() {
  ui.showData()
}
```

**SOLUTION - JavaScript**
as per @Chris G - The main problem here is that the constructor runs long before the user has picked a value. A statement like `this.qtyAskValue = document.querySelector("#qtyAsk").value.trim()` does not extend into the future; it runs when it's called, once, then never again unless you call it again. Therefore `this.qtyAskValue` will remain `""` (because that's the initial value).

```
const buyTicket = document.querySelector("#buyTicket")

buyTicket.addEventListener("click", getModalInfo)

class UI {
  constructor() {
    this.show = document.querySelector("#modalContent")
  }
  showData() {
    const qtyAskValue = document.querySelector("#qtyAsk").value.trim()

    this.show.innerHTML = `<div class="modal-header">
      <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalCenterTitle">Modal title</h5>
      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
      </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
      <p>You are placing an order for ${qtyAskValue} shares of  at</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>`
  }
}
const ui = new UI()

function getModalInfo() {
  ui.showData()
}
```

Comment: Try using 'document.getElementById'  instead of query selector.  Since you're only using it a few times here, both times to grab a single element by their ID already.

Comment: @4cody I tried it does not work

Comment: Have you done a few console.logs to confirm you're actually passing the values into their variables properly?

Comment: You can use `valueAsNumber`. `document.getElementById('qtyAsk').valueAsNumber`

Comment: @Dom it says `NaN`

Comment: @4cody I did ttry console.log but it shows nothing

Comment: The main problem here is that the constructor runs long before the user has picked a value. A statement like `this.qtyAskValue = document.querySelector("#qtyAsk").value.trim()` does not extend into the future; it runs when it's called, once, then never again unless you call it again. Therefore `this.qtyAskValue` will remain `""` (because that's the initial value).

Comment: @ChrisG I will try to move it out of the constructor and I will get back to you.

Comment: Just move the two constructor commands to the top of you `showData()` and it should work fine.

Comment: @ChrisG it works now. Really appreciate explaining it in details. Thank you!